# Sending XML in AJAX request always receives an error

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am sending XML to a particular web service. When I view the response in my browser's network tab, it seems it's a proper request as I expected, but still the `error` callback in my JS code is firing hence handling it as an error instead of making use of the returned response as expected. What could be the cause of this?

```js
const endpoint = "https://secure1.sandbox.directpay.online/API/v6/";

$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#sendBtn").click(function() {
    var x2js = new X2JS();
    var req = "<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>" +
      "<API3G>" +
        "<CompanyToken>TOKEN-TO-BE-PLACED-HERE</CompanyToken>" +
        "<Request>createToken</Request>" +
        "<Transaction>" +
          "<PaymentAmount>450.00</PaymentAmount>" +
          "<PaymentCurrency>USD</PaymentCurrency>" +
          "<CompanyRef>49FKEOA</CompanyRef>" +
          "<RedirectURL>https://secure1.sandbox.directpay.online/payv2.php?ID=TOKEN-HERE</RedirectURL>" +
          "<BackURL>http://localhost/computicket_node_server/</BackURL>" +
          "<CompanyRefUnique>0</CompanyRefUnique>" +
          "<PTL>5</PTL>" +
        "</Transaction>" +
        "<Services>" +
          "<Service>" +
            "<ServiceType>5525</ServiceType>" +
            "<ServiceDescription>Flight from Malawi to India</ServiceDescription>" +
            "<ServiceDate>2013/12/20 19:00</ServiceDate>" +
          "</Service>" +
        "</Services>" +
      "</API3G>";

    $.ajax({
      url: endpoint,
      type: "POST",
      data: req,
      //timeout: 5000,
      dataType: "text/xml",
      success: function(response) {
        var res = JSON.stringify(x2js.xml_str2json(response));
        console.log(res);
        document.getElementById("response").innerHTML = res;
      },
      error: function(xhr, status, error) {
        console.log(xhr, status, error);
      }
    });
  });
});
```

[The results that I am getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JaYhW.png)

Comment: The cause of this is because the server is not responding with a successful HTTP status, either due to a configuration problem or issue with the data you send. What is the exact error you get? It should tell you in the network tab of dev tools. Then you can start to debug this.

Comment: What does `console.log(xhr, status, error);` output?

Comment: Alright, the status code is 200 which suggest that the request got through to the server just fine. As of the actual response is as valid as the documentation depicted included within is a code 000 which suggests a successful process.

Comment: If the response code is 200 yet the `success` handler isn't firing then this is most likely a CORS issue, but if that was the case you should be seeing big 'No access control headers...' errors in the console.

Comment: I have edited the post to add a screenshot of the results in the network tab. tale a look. And yes @RoryMcCrossan , I am getting the CORS alert yet the server is still giving me the requested info

Comment: Can you also show the response headers, please?

Comment: Check the actual console for errors, not the network tab.

Answer (score 0):

Is dataType not the responding type? You should use contentType

```
contentType: "application/xml",
```

Don't know what type you expect to get back, I think you can avoid it.

Comment: Once I change from dataType to contentType, I am not getting any response from the server at all

Comment: could you please try application/xml as type.

Comment: Is this attribute necessary for your request?

Comment: I have but still gets the same result. Error callback persists. and Actually I am expecting XML in the result. I want to do for now is console.log the result, but I cant since the error callback is firing instead of the success

Comment: The dataType attribute is not necessary, and I have removed it. But nothing has changed. I still get the expected result from the server but yet the error callback is executing. All I want is to make use of the data I get from the web-service